# vb.net datagridview sort a result column according to the number value in a string

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

In my vb.net application, I have a datagridview which use the default sorting function. One of the result column type is string, but I want to sort it according to the number value when the first part are the same.

In the datagridview I retrieve 3 column of values: GOODS_NO, REGISTER_ID and DISTRIBUTOR.

The default sorting result of the register_ID is:

AB1001-1

AB1001-10

AB1001-11

AB1001-12

AB1001-13

AB1001-14

AB1001-2

AB1001-3

AB1001-4

AB1001-5

AB1001-6

AB1001-7

AB1001-8

AB1001-9

But this sequence not meaningful to user, what user want to see is:

AB1001-1

AB1001-2

AB1001-3

AB1001-4

AB1001-5

AB1001-6

AB1001-7

AB1001-8

AB1001-9

AB1001-10

AB1001-11

AB1001-12

AB1001-13

AB1001-14

Is this possible? How can achieve it?

Comment: you use query for displaying data in that use order by clause

Comment: Hi Pradnya, thanks for the quick reply, but the database data also in string format, so the sorting result is the same.

Comment: use this link [http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_sort.htm]

Comment: Hi Pradnya, this link is broken.:(

Comment: sorry for that .. :(